# XML Parsing Error Expected: </link>

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project. I need to submit it to Google webmaster tools and for that I had to submit sitemap in XML format to Google. Soe I created a dynamic sitemap generation script on my localhost (Xampp 3.2.2). All went fine and I got this XML rendered in the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
                http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/moulana_online/site/home</loc>
        <lastmod>2016-03-03T10:27:22-08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/moulana_online/site/about-us</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-11-22T00:41:38-08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/moulana_online/site/our-mission</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-11-22T01:24:30-08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/moulana_online/site/moulana-dr-nabi-raza-abidi</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-11-30T17:29:32-08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>http://localhost/moulana_online/site/contact-us</loc>
        <lastmod>2015-11-16T03:00:53-08:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>hourly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

But as soon as I uploaded my script to live site (http://www.moulanaonline.com/sitemap) hosted on IIS server. It gave me this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </link>.
Location: http://www.moulanaonline.com/sitemap
Line Number 69, Column 3:
</head>
--^
```

I am still unable to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The xml that you provided is not the one you are using, because it does not even have `69` lines. Please update the question with right data.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clearly referring to a different file than you posted. You can see this by the error message mentioning line 69, where it says it read `</head>`, while the file you posted has only 40 lines.

So either your upload was wrong or the server means another file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it may be a directory browsing issue on IIS server. Since I am unable to access files directly in my browser (don't know why), my sitemap controller may not be able to locate the correct xml file before rendering it in browser. On the other hand this is not the case on my localhost, I can access files directly. What do you say?

Comment: Turns out that my IIS server is not allowing .xml files to be requested.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. It was a file request issue on IIS server. IIS server was not allowing any .XML file to be requested and was producing a 404 not found error. This caused my sitemap generation script unable to load proper xml file being created dynamically. Added xml in following directives in `web.config`:

```
<rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
   <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="woff|ttf|svg|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|xml" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```